# Passing Hebrew encoded text by AJAX (windows 1255)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, encoding

When making an AJAX call from the client, the server responds with Hebrew text. The PHP page that returns the result is in Windows-1255. 
For some reason, the result encoding is not Windows-1255, and all I see is gibberish instead of Hebrew. 
The result purposely contains HTML tags.

I've tried urlencoding, base64 encoding, nothing works.

Thanks!

Comment: The default encoding for HTML has been ISO-8859-1 but nowadays UTF-8 is more usual. Windows-1255 is almost the same as ISO-8859-8. You must check if the server responds with the right encoding. I suggest that you change to UTF-8 and you can handle any character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all i needed to do is put this in the respone php file

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1255');

10x everyone!!!

Comment: Chen, even though it works now, you'd be doing yourself a Huge favor if you converted to UTF-8 and never look back. It's the standard these days and ANSI codepages are the main reason why so many Hebrew websites suck and look like garbage on different browsers.

Comment: i prommise that from now on i'll go on utf 10q

Answer (score 4):

Can't you change it so that the server return UTF-8 instead of 1255?

There's absolutely no reason these days to continue using ANSI.

Answer (score 1):

beware: AJAX works only with UTF8, so be sure to convert characters before sending them, otherwise you can get mangled characters in Javascript.

Comment: Not true, but not using UTF-8 is asking for problems.

Answer (score 1):

you should also not use the string from get data,
create a new srting...

Answer (score 0):

What encoding is the web page containing the AJAX call/display?